# How to serialize null values in array?

Tags: protobuf-net, grpc-dotnet

I am working with protobuf-net v3.0.101 on Windows platform and getting the below exception for null values in String array while serializing it using grpc protobuf-net:

I have defined my DataContract like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class StringArray
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string[] StrArray;
}
```

Here is my actual message which I am try to serialize:

```
var stringArray = new StringArray() { StrArray = new string[] { "1", "2", null, "3" } };
```

And, this is how I am calling Serializer:

```
method.RequestMarshaller.ContextualSerializer(request, transmitPayload);
```

Here is the exception :

```
FAIL: Error: Unhandled exception in required test method. An element of type System.String was null; this might be as contents in a list/array. (System.NullReferenceException: An element of type System.String was null; this might be as contents in a list/array
   at ProtoBuf.Internal.ThrowHelper.ThrowNullRepeatedContents[T]()
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.RepeatedSerializer`2.Write[TEnumerator](State& state, Int32 fieldNumber, SerializerFeatures category, WireType wireType, TEnumerator& values, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.VectorSerializer`1.Write(State& state, Int32 fieldNumber, SerializerFeatures category, WireType wireType, T[] values, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.RepeatedSerializer`2.WriteRepeated(State& state, Int32 fieldNumber, SerializerFeatures features, TCollection values, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at proto_29(State& , StringArray )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.State.SerializeRoot[T](T value, ISerializer`1 serializer)
   at ProtoBuf.MeasureState`1..ctor(TypeModel model, T& value, Object userState, Int64 abortAfter)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Measure[T](T value, Object userState, Int64 abortAfter)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ProtoBuf.IMeasuredProtoOutput<System.Buffers.IBufferWriter<System.Byte>>.Measure[T](T value, Object userState)
   at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.ProtoBufMarshallerFactory.ContextualSerialize[T](T value, SerializationContext context)
```

Comment: Uuh.. the exception says "you have a null value in your string array", and you have a null value in the 3rd position of your string array

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is: the underlying protobuf format *has no concept of null*. There is simply no way for me to encode that in an array, in an obvious way.

In V2 we did something whereby all array elements were (with this feature enabled) wrapped in an extra layer to allow us to interpret null values, but this takes more space on the wire, is not an in-place silent replacement, and isn't obvious to interpret. I haven't yet re-added that in V3, but we could do if it was highly needed. However, a lazy way of doing this today would be to serialize `Foo[]` where `Foo` is a type that *has* a `string` as the only member, field 1. It could be a value-type - possibly even a `readonly struct record` with a single field.

Comment: 1) Which solution would be more performant, serialize it as `Foo[]` or that 'something' solution for V3 ?
2) If fixing at V3 would be performant, then how much is that effort ? When it can be released ?
3) Any implementation detail how its been done for V2, would help me understand its complexity.
Thanks.

Comment: @Priyanshu the bytes on the wire would be identical; what it would save is the extra code and allocations on the caller side (i.e. your code). The implementation delta for null tracking is basically some extra code to spoof the extra layer - probably not massive, maybe a half day to a day's effort; the edge cases have already been considered (thanks to V2), so there aren't many outstanding questions - just: finding the time to do it (ultimately, it comes out if my personal family time, etc)

Comment: I have solved this problem by defining `readonly struct record` as you mentioned. But this solution is not much scalable, we have lots of lots of dto which contains array or another object which again contains array. Another problem is, I am not able to distinguish between an empty array or null array at the receiver end, both gets deserialized as null.

Same is the problem with IEnumerable<T>, we can't send null values, and can't distinguish b/w null and empty list. Solution for these problems is must for us. Can you guide me how can I fix it at open-source repo. Thanks.

Comment: @Priyanshu it would take me quite a long time to explain how to fix it - somewhere in the same region as the time needed for me to actually fix it; is this professional/corporate work? at risk of sounding crass: if it is a "must", would sponsoring the change be a viable option?

Comment: this question is for my understanding.. So the solution that you would be doing is to enable 'SupportNull' property that can be used to override runtimetype model like this RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(SomeObject)][1].SupportNull = true; ?
Then at my end, I need to Create new RuntimeTypeModel and set this property as true for all arrays in dto ?

Comment: @Priyanshu well, *yeeeesssss* - but: the code that *provides* that feature doesn't exit in v3, is the point; someone (probably me) would need to go and write that

Comment: I have another requirement for arrays/lists, I want to distinguish between null and empty array after deserialization. Today as per the design protobuf doesn't write anything on the wire in this case and as per the ProtoContract, it assign value at the receiver end. Do you think there should be a way in protobuf-net to define in runtimeTypeModel or in an attribute to receive the same value as passed ? This way users get an ability to distinguish between null or an empty case. I can help with the PR, but need your input first.

Comment: @Priyanshu that's not a thing that can be done directly; at least, not except for some primitives (int/float/bool/double/etc); there is literally no way to represent a set of zero elements outside of that niche case; you can work around it with a separate bool property that indicates whether the data should be considered there or not - trust me: I am painfully familiar with the underlying data protocol here